# How to share state between StencilJS components

Tags: stenciljs

I would like to share state between my StencilJS components. So I checked out the Redux implementation which they promote on their [API site](https://stenciljs.com/docs/stencil-redux#5-initialize-store). It does something like

```
@Prop({ context: "store" }) store: Store;
```

But now I just red the [BREAKING_CHANGES](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md), which described that using `context` is deprecated. I actually liked using `context` but if this is deprecated, how can I share state between my components. I'm not really looking forward to pass everything from parent to child to etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `context` API, even though deprecated, will still work, at least until the `@stencil/redux` package has been updated.

If you're looking for a simple alternative for global state, you should have a look at `@stencil/store` (https://github.com/manucorporat/stencil-store/tree/master/packages/stencil-store). It allows you to create a store with `createStore(initalState)` and returns a `state` reference which you can just import and reference in your component. When the store's state changes, the library will take care of triggering an update of your component.